# Refresh no data attr para mostrar no popover bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Tenho uma `table` que possui uma `td` com o seguinte código :

```
.append($("<td class='popOverStatusAlmo' data-container='body' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-content='" + this.StatusAlmoxarifado + "' style='color:red'></td>").text(this.StatusAlmoxarifado != "" ? this.StatusAlmoxarifado.toUpperCase().substring(0, 15) + "..." : this.StatusAlmoxarifado));
```

Toda vez que o usuário passa o mouse sobre a `td` eu disparo um evento de `mouseenter` e mostro o `popover`.

Só que nessa mesma `table` o usuário pode alterar o status que é demonstrado no `popover`.

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass("fa-pencil-square-o")) {
    $this = $(e.target).parent().parent();
    $("#txbMyModalStatusAlmoxarifado").val($($this).find("td:nth-child(7)").data("content"));
    $("#myModalStatusAlmoxarifado").modal("show");
}
```

Repare que eu pego o valor do `data("content")` e coloco esse valor em um `textarea` para poder editar. E é aí que inicia meu problema.

Quando salvo a informação editada, eu insiro o `val()` do `textarea` no `attr data`.

```
$("#btnModalStatusAlmoxarifado").click(function () {
    var linha = $this;
    var comentario = $("#txbMyModalStatusAlmoxarifado").val();
    var pim = $(linha).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    modificarStatusAlmoxarifado(pim, comentario);    
    $(linha).find("td:nth-child(7)").text(comentario.toUpperCase().substring(0, 15) + "...");
    $(linha).find("td:nth-child(7)").data('content', 'ANDERSON');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Coloquei Anderson só para testar.

Aparentemente funciona, pois se clico para editar ele leva o Anderson para o `textarea` do `modal`, mas se passo o mouse sobre o campo ele mostra o valor antigo e não o que eu salvei.

Existe alguma forma de atualizar o `popver` para ele mostrar o novo valor sem ter que recarregar a tela inteira?

Comment: Precisa ver como é montado o popover, se é lido dinamicamente cada vez que exibe, ou quando inicia ele lê o atributo e deixa em um `div` pronto por exemplo. Nesse caso, teria que "recriar" o popover depois de mudar o valor do atributo, algo como `$('#idDoElemento').popover();`

Comment: Obrigado por comentar.

Não consegui, adicionei a seguinte linha : 

`$(linha).find("td:nth-child(7)").data('content', 'ANDERSON').popover(); `   

Mas ele não recarrega. 

Eu monto o popover quando crio a table.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o `bootstrap` sempre pega o que está no **data-content** quando gera o popover, e depois não atualiza mais. Uma solução é dizer que o *content* do popover será dinâmico, o mudar a propriedade **data-content** para outra, como **data-texto**, para evitar que o `bootstrap` gere o popover com conteúdo fixo.

Então, ao iniciar o popover, usar o parâmtro *content* e pegar o valor sempre dinamicamente, assim (pegando seu exemplo de código):

```
$(linha).find("td:nth-child(7)").popover({
    content: function() { 
        return $(this).data('texto'); 
   }
});
```

Obviamente, mudar todo o código para ler o **data-texto** no lugar de **data-content**.

Fiz um jsfiddle para testar, veja aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2758/

Espero que ajude.